# is there an open source social single-sign-on facade?

Tags: single-sign-on, social-networking

I recently found the [jainrain engage product](http://www.janrain.com/products/engage/get-janrain-engage) that helps streamline the process of connecting a drupal application to single-sign-on of all major social network.

I appreciate it because it reduces to 1 API all the different APIs you may encounter on the different networks.

Is there an open source version of such a 1-size-fits-all API ?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've been using the [OpenID Selector module](http://drupal.org/project/openid_selector) lately, with good results. It doesn't offer all the functionality that Janrain's solution does, but it's a good start.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this one? http://hybridauth.sourceforge.net/